# Count children elements with inline style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm stuck on how to get number of all elements that has inline style.

```
var galleryElements = document.getElementsByClassName("popup-gallery")[0].children;

    $('.myButton').click(function() {
    
        var totalItems = galleryElements.length;
        var itemsWithStyle = ($(galleryElements).css('display') == 'inline').length;
        
        if (totalItems == itemsWithStyle){
            /* do something */
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say I have a NodeList of the children of some div, i.e.

```
const div = document.querySelector('#target');
const children = div.children;
```

If I want to get the number of children with the `display` attribute set to `inline`, then I can iterate through `children` and increment a counter each time I encounter a child element with the `display` attribute set to `inline`.

For example:

```
let count = 0;
for (let child of children) {
  if (child.style.display === 'inline') count++;
}
```

Where `count` represents the number of child elements of the parent div that have a `display` attribute set to `inline`.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a tally of both inline (including inline-block) and other. If there is a class associated with the element, it will report back that as well.

```js
$('.myButton').click(function() {
  let inline = [],  block = []
  $('.popup-gallery *').each(function() {
    let tg = $(this).prop('tagName').toLowerCase()
    if ($(this).attr('class')) tg += "." + $(this).attr('class');
    if (['inline','inline-block'].includes($(this).css('display'))) inline.push(tg)
    else block.push(tg)
  })
  console.log('inline',inline)
  console.log('not-inline',block)
  console.log('inline/total',inline.length + "/" + (inline.length + block.length))
  console.log('has inline elements?',inline.length>0)
});
```

```css
.special{
display:inline;
}

.special-ib{
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='popup-gallery'>
  <div>A div
    <ul>
      <li>li list - <i>italics...</i></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class='special'>inline div</div>
  <div class='special-ib'>inline-block div</div>
  <p>paragraph</p>
  <span>span, <dd>dd</dd></span>
</div>

<button class='myButton'>Click me </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are in fact checking if all gallery elements are `display: inline`, so you can simplify your code a bit:

```js
const $galleryElements = $('.popup-gallery').first().children();

$('.myButton').click(function() {
    const areAllInline = $galleryElements.filter(function () {
        $(this).css('display') !== 'inline';
    }).length === 0;
        
    if (areAllInline) {
        /* do something */
    }
});
```

If there are no elements with `display` *different than* `inline`, you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

this is without jquery

You can check this out for starters:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

basic

```
<h1 id="hello">index.html</h1>

<-- css -->

#hello {display: inline;}

// js

const title = document.getElementById('hello');
let res = window.getComputedStyle(title)
let count = 0;

if(res.getPropertyValue('display') === 'inline') {
    console.log('yes')
    count ++;
    console.log(count)
// 1
}
```

what I learned:
" The object from getComputedStyle is read-only, and should be used to inspect the element's style — including those set by a  element or an external stylesheet.
The element.style object should be used to set styles on that element, or inspect styles directly added to it from JavaScript manipulation or the global style attribute."

Answer (score 0):

These answers are good, however I feel it is even easier than how others are solving this problem.

```js
console.log(
  [...document.querySelectorAll(".popup-gallery")]
    .filter(element => 
      "inline" == 
      window.getComputedStyle(element)
        .getPropertyValue("display")
    ).length
);
```